# How do I connect JProfiler on a JBoss 7.x server in Domain mode?

Tags: jboss7.x, jprofiler

I want to profile a server (JVM) that is part of a JBoss 7.1.3 domain. The Server Integration wizard of JProfiler only modifies standalone.sh, which is of no use in domain mode. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

For application servers that don't have an integration wizard, use the [Generic] integration wizard. It will give you a VM parameter that has to be added to the java invocation of the application server.